# Image not complete

Tags: pstricks, standalone, pst-labo

I'm starting to use pstricks but I'm having problems with the size of my images. As I want to export the resulting image, I used the class standalone. Problem: When exporting, only part of the image is displayed.

My code :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pst-labo}

\colorlet{myfill}{brown!60}
\newcommand{\potence}{
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](0,-0.1)(0.25,13)  
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-0.25,-0.25)(5,0) 
}

\newcommand{\pince}{
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-0.75,-0.1)(2,0.1)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-0.75,-0.35)(-.5,0.35)
    \pscircle[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](0,0){.2}
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](1,-0.25)(2.4,0.25)
}

\newcommand{\supportElevateur}{
    \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill, linearc=.05](.25,2.25)(3.25,1.25)(.25,0.25)(1.25,0.25)(4.25,1.25)(1.25,2.25)
    \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill, linearc=.05](4.25,2.25)(1.25,1.25)(4.25,0.25)(3.25,0.25)(.25,1.25)(3.25,2.25)
    \psline(.25,1.25)(4.5,1.25)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](4.5,1.5)(4.75,1)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](0,2.5)(4.5,2.25)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](0,0.25)(4.5,0)
    }
\begin{document}
\psset{unit=0.5cm}
\pspicture
\psgrid[subgriddiv=1, griddots=10, gridlabels=5pt, gridwidth=0.5pt](-1,-1)(15,15)


 \pstDosage[ niveauReactifBurette =25, glassType=erlen]
 \rput{0}(-4,0){\potence}
 \rput{0}(-3.9,10){\pince}

\psline[linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(1,12)(-1.5,12)
\rput(3.5,12){Burette graduée}

\psline[linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(0.5,4)(-1.5,4)
\rput(2.5,4){erlenmeyer}

\psline[linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(0.5,1.75)(-1.5,1.75)
\rput{0}(3.0,1.75){barreau aimanté}

\psline[linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(1.5,0.5)(-0.5,0.5)
\rput{0}(5,0.5){agitateur magnétique}

\psline[linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(-7,10)(-5,10)
\rput{0}(-8,10){pince}

\psline[linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(-6,7)(-4,7)
\rput{0}(-7.2,7){potence}

\endpspicture
        
\end{document}
```

And the export :

[image]

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have not explicitly passed the options to `standalone` and the `pspicture` environment which is used as a clipping box. Try this modification:

```latex
\documentclass[border=2pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pst-labo}

\colorlet{myfill}{brown!60}
\newcommand{\potence}{
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](0,-0.1)(0.25,13)  
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-0.25,-0.25)(5,0) 
}

\newcommand{\pince}{
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-0.75,-0.1)(2,0.1)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-0.75,-0.35)(-.5,0.35)
    \pscircle[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](0,0){.2}
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](1,-0.25)(2.4,0.25)
}

\newcommand{\supportElevateur}{
    \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill, linearc=.05](.25,2.25)(3.25,1.25)(.25,0.25)(1.25,0.25)(4.25,1.25)(1.25,2.25)
    \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill, linearc=.05](4.25,2.25)(1.25,1.25)(4.25,0.25)(3.25,0.25)(.25,1.25)(3.25,2.25)
    \psline(.25,1.25)(4.5,1.25)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](4.5,1.5)(4.75,1)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](0,2.5)(4.5,2.25)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](0,0.25)(4.5,0)
    }
\begin{document}
\psset{unit=0.5cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-4.5,-1.5)(11,16)% here
\psgrid[subgriddiv=1, griddots=10, gridlabels=5pt, gridwidth=0.5pt](-1,-1)(15,15)

\pstDosage[ niveauReactifBurette =25, glassType=erlen]
\rput{0}(-4,0){\potence}
\rput{0}(-3.9,10){\pince}

\psline[linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(1,12)(-1.5,12)
\rput(3.5,12){Burette graduée}

\psline[linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(0.5,4)(-1.5,4)
\rput(2.5,4){erlenmeyer}

\psline[linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(0.5,1.75)(-1.5,1.75)
\rput{0}(3.0,1.75){barreau aimanté}

\psline[linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(1.5,0.5)(-0.5,0.5)
\rput{0}(5,0.5){agitateur magnétique}

\psline[linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(-7,10)(-5,10)
\rput{0}(-8,10){pince}

\psline[linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(-6,7)(-4,7)
\rput{0}(-7.2,7){potence}

\end{pspicture}
        
\end{document}
```

In my distribution (TeX Live 2021) it compiles without major problem using `dvips/ps2pdf` and `lualatex`.

[image: Output-lualatex]

Note: I changed the syntax plain TeX to LaTeX for the `pspicture` environment and remove `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (no longer required).

Comment: thanks for your help